# no matching function call unresolved function type

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++11

I'm having a problem with this code, it says that there is no matching function call for times, although I'm using the same data types and the number of parameter is the same, can anyone help me please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include<list>
#include<deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;


template<typename F, typename Arg, typename T>
void times(F func, Arg A, int n, T typeval)    // call func(arg,n, typeval)
{
    auto t1 = system_clock::now();
    func(A, n, typval);
    auto t2 = system_clock::now();
    auto dms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2-t1);
    cout << "f(x) took " << dms.count() << " milliseconds\n";
}



int random_gen(int& i){
    default_random_engine re { std::random_device()() };
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
    auto r= bind(dist,re);
    int x =r();
    return x;
    //return rand();
}

string random_gen(string& s)
{
    string Result;          // string which will contain the result
    ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion
    convert << rand();
    return convert.str();
}

template<typename SequenceContainer, typename T>
void build_cont(SequenceContainer& seq, int n, T valtype)
{
    for(int i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
        T gen = random_gen(valtype);
        typename SequenceContainer::iterator it = find_if(seq.begin(), seq.end(), [gen] (const typename SequenceContainer::reference & val) { return gen < val; } );
        seq.insert(it, gen);
    }
    for(auto i:seq)
        cout<<i<<endl;
}
int main() {
    int n=10;
    vector<int> v;
    list<int>ls;
    deque<int> deq;
   cout<<"vector of int"<<endl;
    times(build_cont, v, n, 0);

//  string stemp = "";
//    cout<<"vector of strings"<<endl;
//    build_cont(sv, n, stemp);
//    cout<<"list of strings"<<endl;
//    build_cont(sls, n, stemp);
//    cout<<"deque of strings"<<endl;
//    build_cont(sdeq, n, stemp);
//    
    return 0;
}
```

when I run build_cont it runs just fine, but the code stop working when I put it inside the times function?
any suggestions.

Comment: post a (complete) example of the code that fails, with diagnostic messages

Comment: you have a typo: `func(A, n, typval);` should be `func(A, n, typeval);`.

Comment: Can you post errors? When you passing `build_cont` you should specify it's template params, like `build_cont<Blah, Blah>`

Comment: `default_random_engine re { std::random_device()() };` ??

Comment: this is a random number generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the template parameters for `build_cont`

```
times(build_cont<std::vector<int>, int>, v, n, 0);
```

Comment: And `func(A, n, typval);` should be `func(A, n, typeval);`.